# Adjust brightness function is gone after upgrading Windows

Tags: windows-8, upgrade

I recently installed Windows 8 on my Sony Vaio (VPCCW17FX).

Now my adjust brightness function is missing. It is gone from the power option as well. How do I fix this problem?

I also had a chat with Sony and they said they don't recommend upgrading to Windows 8 and they will not provide support if done so. What is my solution?

Comment: What about something from these steps? http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6041-screen-brightness-adjust-windows-8-a.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you installed any drivers by yourself, or if they were installed by Windows. But the better option would be install a driver or software that is responsible for adjusting your brightness. In case it won't install, try to use Windows 7/XP mode.